# Custom menu, android, transparent activity?

Tags: android, android-activity, menu, transparent

I need to create a custom menu for android.. but Im not sure of where to begin..
I have seen a bunch of different approaches and the best one I have found is to simply create a new activity with a transparent background.. the idea is that the menu should open as a smal column to the right of the screen but just simply "overlay" the other layout/activity/views.
The thing Im not sure about is.. if I create this actvity as a menu and set the background to be transparent, what happens if the user then presses a button on the actvity that gets "overlayed"?.. will the menu-activity disappears and the activity trigger the click-event?..

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A separate activity with mostly transparent background and some buttons is an option.  Invoke that activity with `startActivityForResult`. In the handler for your buttons, `setResult` indicating which button was pressed and call `finish()` to close the "menu" activity.  Then in the activity that "triggered" menu, override `onActivityResult` where you would look at the returned code and perform corresponding actions.

In main activity:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle bdl) {
    ...

    findViewById(R.id.button_menu).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void click(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(MenuActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(i, REQUEST_MENU);
        }
    }

    ...
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if(requestCode == REQUEST_MENU) {
        switch(resultCode) {
            case MENU_ITEM_1:
                ...
                break;
            case MENU_ITEM_2:
                ...
                break;
            case MENU_ITEM_3:
                ...
                break;
            default:
                ...
    }
}
```

And in your menu activity:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle bdl) {
    ...

    findViewById(R.id.menu_option_1).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void click(View v) {
            setResult(MENU_ITEM_1);
            finish();
        }

    findViewById(R.id.menu_option_2).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void click(View v) {
            setResult(MENU_ITEM_1);
            finish();
        }

    findViewById(R.id.menu_option_3).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void click(View v) {
            setResult(MENU_ITEM_1);
            finish();
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: But for the button thats on the "main"-activity, and not on the "menu"-activity.. how do I know which button was pressed on the "main"-activity.. cause I guess that once the menu-activity is brought up front.. then if i press in the transparent area, where the "main"-activities button is.. then there wont be any event triggered since the transparent area is a part of the "menu"-activity which overlays the "main"-activity.. sort if like placing an element over an a-link in HTML..
My point is that pressing the transparent area where the button for the "main"-actvity is wont fire any event..or?

Comment: @Inx You do not know.  Android activities are asynchronous.  When the button is pressed to invoke the menu, you open the menu activity and then the code continues straight on.  It's in the `onActivityResult` that you see which button was pressed.

Comment: I think I might have confused you..or either Im confusing myself :)..anyway.. I get the part of how to create the menu.. and make the menu-items trigger evenets (or just plain methods) on the "main"-activity..
But what if the "main"-activity contains a few buttons.. then the user brings up the menu, and he/she doesnt press any of the menu-items.. but instead hs/she presses one of the buttons on the "main"-activity/layout.. would that trigger the event for the specific button on the main-activity..

Comment: @Inx Once the menu activity is opened, you will not be able to click anything on the main activity, as it'll be in the background.  Only after you close the menu activity will the main activity become active again.

Comment: or in other terms.. does an event "bubble" through a transparent layout?

Comment: Ok thanks :),
Is there any other way to achive the effect Im after?

Comment: @Inx I'm not sure what effect you are after.  If you want both menu and main activity to be "active", then you need to make your menu a view with absolute positioning on the screen where you need it.  Create the view, add it last (will appear above others), set position in the code and change its `visibility` to `VISIBLE`.  On click of options, set its visibility to `GONE`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use PopupWindow or custom Dialog for this purpose. To choose the behavior of outer click by setting dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(boolean). And to layout you menu you can simply set layout params to PopupWindow or custom Dialog. Starting activity is not necessary for such operations.